# How to manage building golang projects on travis-ci

Tags: go, travis-ci

I'm developing Golang project and using TravisCI. As dependency tool, Godeps is used.

After running test by git push, something error was happened as below.

```
# command-line-arguments
cmd/proj/main_test.go:6:2: cannot find package 
"command-line-/vendor/github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx/abc" in any of:
/home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.6.linux.amd64/src/command-line-/vendor/github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxx
```

Why it can't find package?
As build log, it seems to work well by go get command.

My travis.yml is here.

```
language: go
sudo: false
go:
  - 1.6
  - tip

services:
  - redis-server

env:
  global:
    - secure: "xxxxx"

script:
  - go fmt ./...
  - go vet $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
  - go test -v cmd/xxxx/*.go -xxxx ${XXXXX}

before_install:
  - go get github.com/tools/godep

branches:
  only:
    - master
```

tip of go version is OK.
But 1.6 or 1.5 version can't run well.

How can I manage that situation?

Comment: If you have checked your dependencies into git under /vendor then Travis does not need to go get godep. For 1.5 you need to set the GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT env var to 1 but godep itself is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The way Go 1.6 manages dependencies is different than Go 1.5 and previous versions.

1.6 introduces the `/vendor` folder. Whenever you import a dependency, if the library exists in `/vendor`, then the library is loaded.

The behavior was introduced in 1.5, but in that version it was experimental. It means that you need to enable it using the `GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1` environment variable.

If you only need to provide support for 1.5 and 1.6, then simply add the variable to Travis when building 1.5 projects.

If you need to extend support also for versions before 1.5, then it's a little bit more complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
Though I set version 1.6 and tit, but tip version can work. But 1.6 can't.
And travis seems to try find package in vendor directory.

Comment: @Harry it would be helpful to have the entire Travis log.